# Software for Image classification

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, neural-network, logistic-regression

Currently I am working for a project to classify a given set of test images into one of the 5 predefined categories. I implemented Logistic Regression with a feature vector of 240 features for each image and trained it using 100 images/ category. The learning accuracy I achieved was ~98% for each category, whereas when tested on validation set consisting of 500 images (100 images/category), only ~57% images were rightly classified.

Please suggest me few libraries/tools which I can use (preferably based on Neural Network) in order to attain higher accuracy.

I tried using a Java based tool, Neurophy ([neuroph.sourceforge.net](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net)) on windows but, it didn't run as expected.

**Edit**: The feature vector were already provided for the project. I am also looking for a better feature extraction tool for Images.

Comment: you are likely overfitting your test set ... try relaxing the restraints slightly or otherwise tweaking them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get help from this paper [Image Classification](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~afra/courses/44/w09/project/report/gu-song-report.pdf)

In My opinion, SVM is relatively better than logistic regression when it comes to multi-class response problems. We use it in e commerce classification of product where there are 1000s of response level and thousands of features.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tags I assume you would like a python package, scikit-learn has good classification routines: [scikit-learn.org](http://scikit-learn.org).

Answer (score 0):

I have had good success using the WEKA tools, you need to isolate the feature set that you are interested in and then apply a classifier from this library. The examples are very clear. http://weka.wikispaces.com